# Want to remove Saleforce1 blue header using Jquery, but getting blocked due to Cross Domain security

Tags: salesforce1-platform, salesforce1-app, cors

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://c.na15.visual.force.com" from "page address is here "accessing a frame with origin "https://na15.salesforce.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

I am using this line of jquery code:

```
console.log(window.parent.$('header'));
```

Requirement is to modify SF1 header or remove.
If I would be able to access element outside , iframe, then i can modify the header.

There is a help link saying something about CORS :[cors](http://www.jamesward.com/2014/06/23/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-for-salesforce-com). But i am understanding how, to achieve this.
My Goal is to modify the header only. why do i need to call Rest Service or Chatter Rest Api

Comment: One solution could be a use of [`Window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). It enables cross-origin communication.

Comment: @mast0r: will it be able to change the html content using jquery.outside the iframe.

Comment: It allows to run a javascript code on the parent page from the iframe. But it is potentially vulnerable. You will have to configure it properly.

Comment: I can not add/change anything in target domain. situation is like: there is a html page, inside this my iframe reside, and i have full control over iframe. but not over main page.

Comment: So you are out of luck then...